# Swift - Get weekOfYear for a DateComponents entry

Tags: swift, calendar

I'm facing some problems to get the weekOfYear for a valid DateComponents value. This code

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let dc = DateComponents(calendar:cal, year: 2023, month: 1, day:12)
let woy = dc.weekOfYear

print("Week of year: \(woy)")
```

generates

```
Week of year: nil
```

as an output.

I've expected `2`...

Comment: Why did you expect 12? 12 January is not the 12th week of 2023 at all, you know.

Comment: Thanks you are right. 
The correct result should be `2`. Nevertheless the resulting `nil` from my demo program is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

`DateComponents` is a simple type. It is merely a collection of date components. It does not do date computations like calculating the week of year. That's the job of `Calendar`. You did not give it a week of year when you initialise the date components, so you get `nil` when you ask for it.

You can ask the calendar to make a `Date` out of the `DateComponents` you have, and ask it what the week of year is:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let dc = DateComponents(calendar:cal, year: 2023, month: 1, day:12)
if let date = cal.date(from: dc) {
    // prints 2 as expected
    print(cal.component(.weekOfYear, from: date))
}
```